# What does "(additional) features" mean in the definition of a structure?

Tags: definition

I am reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) on mathematical structure, and it says "a structure is a set endowed with some additional features".
Features can encompass a metric, a topology, etc...

I'd like to know if there exists a rigorous definition of this meaning of structure, especially of this term "features".

Could "features" mean just a signature along with an interpretation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Definition of a structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084541/definition-of-a-structure) and [Intuition behind a structure of a language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131595/intuition-behind-a-structure-of-a-language-in-mathematical-logic-long-read-but)

Comment: The answer to your question (and to @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment and answer) is: no, "features" in that Wikipedia page is more general, as their example of a topology shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in logic and model theory *structure* means [Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) [see [Structure (Mathematical logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic))].

See e.g. Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/%7Emlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf) page 58:

> A structure is an ordered sequence $\langle A,R_1,\ldots, R_n,F_1,\ldots,F_m,\{ c_i \mid i \in \} \rangle$, where $A$ is a non-empty set [the *domain*]. $R_1,\ldots,R_n$ are *relations* on $A$, $F_1,\ldots,F_m$ are *functions* on $A$, the $c_i$ are elements of $A$ [the *constants*].

So, we have a domain of individuals: the set $A$, and relations and operations on them.

*Note* that in this sense a *signature* is related only to the *language*.

The Bourbaki-like term "[Mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure)" is usually used not in conenction with a formal language, but considering more specifically the relavnt axioms: this is IMO the sense of Wiki's statement "a structure is a set endowed with some additional features on the set (e.g. an operation, relation, metric, or topology)."

There is no contradiction, because operations and metrics are *functions*; also a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) is a function from the *space* $X$ (the domain of the structure) to the collection of subsets of $X$.

Comment: Aren't axioms compulsory in any case ? For example, the very simple structure $(\mathbb Z, +)$ needs axioms in order to define the addition.

Comment: @niobium - maybe not "compulsory" (the def does not refer to axioms) but of course we add specific non-logical symbols, like $+, \in$, in order to develop a mathematical theory, and it is impossible to have an interesting theory adding only the symbols and not the axioms ruling them.