# Confusion in the definition of Algebraic structure, system, operation, magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, binary-operations, groupoids

During studying the text book of abstract algebra by john Farleigh, I encounter with tye definition of binary Algebraic structure. Then I tried to find the difference between binary Algebraic structure and Algebraic structure. I checked on many resources like Wikipedia, proofWiki, and MSE but instead of understanding notion I got confused.
Now I am confused in the definition of
1- Algebraic structure
2- binary Algebraic structure
3- Algebraic system
4- Algebraic operation.
5- Magma.
In the book author says:
**A binary Algebraic structure $ (S,*) $ to be a set S together with a binary operation $ * $ on it.**

But after searching alot, I think the definitions are :

**Algebraic structure**:
An Algebraic structure is a non empty set $S$ together with n binary operations, say $ *_1, *_2, \cdots , *_n $ on
$S$. It is denoted as $( S, *_1, \cdots , *_n  )$ or sometimes as $\langle S, *_1, \cdots , *_n  \rangle  $

**Binary Algebraic structure**:
An Algebraic structure consisting of only one binary operation.

**Algebraic system**:
An Algebraic system is the collection of non empty set $S$ together with set $O$ of finitary operations on $S$, it is denoted by $(S,O)$.

**Algebraic operation**:
An Algebraic operation $ * $ on a non empty set $S$ is a function $$ *:A^n → A$$

**Magma**:
A binary Algebraic structure is also called magma or groupoid.

Are these all definitions correct? I have specially doubt on Algebraic structure and Algebraic system.

Thank you.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804182/what-does-additional-features-mean-in-the-definition-of-a-structure) for *Structure*.

Comment: An [Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) in mathematics is a function having zero, one, or more arguments: its [*arity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). A *binary* operation is a function with two arguments (example: sum of numbers).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry I still didn't understand, what actually is an Algebraic structure and what is different of it with Algebraic system. (In context of Algebra)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, the terms Algebraic structure and system can be use in the same sense. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, no relevant difference between "n binary operations" and "a set of finitary operations". The second one allows for a ternary op, while the first one does not. Is this worth a specific name? NO.